# Why is ios packaging inconsistent with using xcode run directly?

Tags: ios, react-native

The react native project uses xcode to run on the simulator and real machine, and the image resources are displayed normally, but after being packaged into ipa, some images will not be displayed. I've tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, but the result is still the same

Comment: I don’t know react-native but did you all requirements from [image on ios](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images ?)

Comment: I changed the value of resizeMode(Changed from 'center' to 'contain') and it displays normally after packing, although I don't know why.